# Named string interpolation

Tags: c#, strings

On machines where I don't have C# 6 I use this named string interpolation method. I tried to make it as *pretty* a possible as far as good coding practices are concerned but I just can't get rid of the repeating code for braces validation and index incrementation. Somehow I don't like it.

```
public static string FormatFrom(this string text, object args, bool ignoreCase = true)
{
    var substrings = Regex.Split(text, "({{?)([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+)(}}?)");
    var argsType = args.GetType();
    var result = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

    const int leftBraceOffset = 0;
    const int propertyNameOffset = 1;
    const int rightBraceOffset = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++)
    {
        var leftBraceIndex = i + leftBraceOffset;
        var propertyNameIndex = i + propertyNameOffset;
        var rightBraceIndex = i + rightBraceOffset;

        var isPropertyName = substrings[leftBraceIndex] == "{" && substrings[rightBraceIndex] == "}";
        if (isPropertyName)
        {
            var propertyName = substrings[propertyNameIndex];
            var property = argsType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            result.Append(property.GetValue(args));
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }

        var isEscapedPropertyName = substrings[leftBraceIndex] == "{{" && substrings[rightBraceIndex] == "}}";
        if (isEscapedPropertyName)
        {
            result.Append("{").Append(substrings[propertyNameIndex]).Append("}");
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }

        result.Append(substrings[i]);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

---

```
var text = "Lorem {ipsum} {dolor} {{sit}} met.";
var obj = new { ipsum = "abc", dolor = 2.1 };
var text2 = text.FormatFrom(obj);
```

Result:

> Lorem abc 2.1 {sit} met.

Comment: You say C# 6 is not available on those machines. What version do they run instead?

Comment: @Mast the last before C# - Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Can you install the v6 compiler (it's on NuGet) and keep targeting the old framework? All you need is to add a file to your project with the `IFormattable` interface. Jon Skeet did a great demo of it on you tube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a seriously impressive answer from Heslacher. I remember doing something like this a while ago (turns out to be nearly 5 years ago) and thought I solved it completely with regexes. I've slightly modified it to use an object as it originally used a dictionary:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static Regex _parameterReplacementRegex =
            new Regex("(?<!{){(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)}(?!})",
                    RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture |
                    RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static string FormatFrom(this string text, object args)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        }
        if (args == null)
        {
            return ReplaceDoubleBraces(text);
        }

        var argsType = args.GetType();
        var result = _parameterReplacementRegex.Replace(text, match =>
        {
            var paramName = match.Groups["name"].Value;
            var propertyInfo = argsType.GetProperty(paramName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                return propertyInfo.GetValue(args).ToString();
            }
            return "{" + paramName + "}";
        });
        return ReplaceDoubleBraces(result);
    }

    private static string ReplaceDoubleBraces(string result)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(result, "(\\{|\\}){2}", "$1");
    }
}
```

You'll notice my Regex uses a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead to only capture non 'esacped' curly braces. I then use a MatchEvaluator delegate (called on each match) to replace it with the value from the args object or put the string back in its original format if there is no entry in the args object (`return "{" + paramName + "}";`). That could be modified to throw if you'd rather.

I'd also suggest the following additional test case:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void FormatFromTestArgsNullEscapesCurlyBrace()
{
    string expected = "{land}";
    string actual;
    actual = "{{land}}".FormatFrom(null);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

To ensure it has consistent behaviour with `string.Format`.

I'm sure that this answer is less performant but I find it easier to reason about (but I am a Regex nut).

As a final point, I'd rename the method `With` or `FormatWith` :)

Comment: My first version of this method was based on regex replace but I didn't notice that I can actually handle the replace/match _event_ and put a new value already there.  I used a _rookie_ replace. This is pretty cool ;-)

Comment: `FormatWith` vs `FormatFrom`... The first version was indeed `FormatWith` ;-) but then I decided to turn it around and instead of trying to put all properties into a string I look which properties I want to have and pull them from the object as needed. This way I can use a _big_ object as a source and get only a few properties. I think this might be cheaper.

Answer (score 7):

- Always check the argument which is reffered by `this` in an extension method against `null` to early throw and return. Sure one could say it doesn't matter, because it will throw an `ArgumentNullException` but that would be thrown from the `Regex.Split()` method.
- You don't check for `args == null` either.
- The optional argument `ignoreCase` isn't used anywhere in that method so it can safely removed.
- if by accident the property of the anonymous object isn't spelled exactly like in the string, the call to `argsType.GetProperty()` will return `null` and an `NullReferenceException` is thrown. Maybe it would be better for such a case to just assume it isn't a property. I will come back to this later.
- if the passed in text only contains `{` the code will throw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception. This can be prevented by returning early if the length of `text` is `< 3`.
- if the `Length` of `substrings` will be `< 3` we can return early by returning `text`.
- the regex pattern does not allow single letter variables being passed. So a text like `{i}` won't be matched.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
public static string FormatFrom(this string text, object args)
{
    if (text == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("text"); }

    if (text.Length < 3 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || args==null) { return text; }

    var substrings = Regex.Split(text, "({{?)([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+)(}}?)")
                          .Where(s => s != string.Empty).ToArray();

    if (substrings.Length < 3) { return text; }

    var argsType = args.GetType();
    var result = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

    const int propertyNameOffset = 1;
    const int rightBraceOffset = 2;

    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;

    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++)
    {

        var possibleLeftBraces = substrings[i];
        var possibleRightBraces = substrings[i + rightBraceOffset];
        var propertyName = substrings[i + propertyNameOffset];

        var isPropertyName = possibleLeftBraces == "{" && possibleRightBraces == "}";
        if (isPropertyName)
        {
            var property = argsType.GetProperty(propertyName, bindingFlags);
            if (property == null)
            {
                result.Append("{").Append(propertyName).Append("}");
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append(property.GetValue(args, null));
            }
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }

        var isEscapedPropertyName = possibleLeftBraces == "{{" && possibleRightBraces == "}}";
        if (isEscapedPropertyName)
        {
            result.Append("{").Append(propertyName).Append("}");
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }

        result.Append(substrings[i]);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

which will pass all of these tests

```
[TestMethod()]
public void FormatFromTestStringEmptyShouldPass()
{
    string expected = string.Empty;
    string actual = string.Empty.FormatFrom(null);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

}
[TestMethod(),ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void FormatFromTestStrinNullShouldPass()
{

    string actual = ((string)null).FormatFrom(null);

    Assert.Inconclusive("Shouldn't happen !");

}
[TestMethod()]
public void FormatFromTestArgsNullShouldPass()
{
    string expected = "lala";
    string actual = "lala".FormatFrom(null);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

}
[TestMethod()]
public void FormatFromTestParamsButArgsNullShouldPass()
{
    string expected = "{land}";
    string actual = "{land}".FormatFrom(null);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

}
[TestMethod()]
public void FormatFromTestArgsNotNullShouldPass()
{
    string expected = "germany";
    string actual = "{land}".FormatFrom(new { land = "germany" });
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

}
[TestMethod()]
public void FormatFromTestArgsNotNullButWrongShouldPass()
{
    string expected = "{land}"; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
    string actual;
    actual = "{land}".FormatFrom(new { lan = "germany" });
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I'm always forgetting about the null checks ;-) If there was always a way to speparate the _workig_ code from the _defensive_ one.

Comment: @t3chb0t aspect oriented programming / PostSharp on .NET...