# Make utility using LINQ

Tags: c#, functional-programming, linq

`Make()` takes projects with a list of tuples representing project references in the form of `(Dependency, Dependent)` and returns projects in the order to be build:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var projects = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
    var dependencies = new[] { ("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("e", "f"), ("c", "f"), ("f", "d") };
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Join(", ", Make(projects, dependencies))); // a, e, b, c, f, d
}
```

Where:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Make(
    IEnumerable<string> projects, 
    IEnumerable<(string Dependency, string Dependent)> references)
{
    var dependents = new HashSet<string>(references.Select(d => d.Dependent));
    var build = new HashSet<string>(projects.Except(dependents));
    return 
        !projects.Any() ? Enumerable.Empty<string>() :
        !build.Any() ? throw new Exception("Circled references detected.") :
        build.Concat(Make(
            projects.Except(build).ToArray(),
            references.Where(r => !build.Contains(r.Dependency)).ToArray()));
}
```

What about run-time complexity of this one? Could it be optimized?

Comment: I looks like there is already an _official_ algorithm for that. See [Nikita B's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/156610/59161) to a similar question of mine. However, not so compact. Although I think it could be improved.

Comment: @t3chb0t Yep, I just tried to be immutable and as concise as possible (as usual :), it is almost the same. There is one in [Cracking coding interview](https://www.amazon.com/Cracking-Coding-Interview-Programming-Questions/dp/0984782850) on page 250 (common, everybody has this book :) - but there it looks really, really scary :)

Comment: You probably should add a notice in your questions that reviews should favor functional solutions ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Exit early

Instead of stuffing everything in one return statements, return as early as possible.

```
if (!projects.Any()) return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

can be the first statement of your method. It saves recreating the hashset objects and it makes the flow of your method with its recursion more clear. I think sacrificing a bit of "conciseness" for readability is worth it.

## `ToArray`

Are unnecessary and cause additional loops over your sets.

## `Except` and `HashSet`

`Enumerable.Except` is already implemented using sets. The second argument is added to a set and the first is streamed through it. Creating the `HashSet` manually is a wasted effort. See [the reference source.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,899)

So `dependents` can just be:

```
var dependents = references.Select(d => d.Dependent);
```

## `Contains` and `HashSet`

`Contains` on the other hand benefits from the `HashSet` overload, since the `Enumerable.Contains` implementation just loops over the sequence. So `build` should be a `HashSet` to cope with larger inputs. While we're at it, we're using `Linq`, so `ToHashSet`().

```
static IEnumerable<string> Make(
    IEnumerable<string> projects,
    IEnumerable<(string Dependency, string Dependent)> references)
{
    if (!projects.Any())
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
    var dependents = references.Select(d => d.Dependent);
    var build = projects.Except(dependents).ToHashSet();
    if (!build.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("Circled references detected.");
    }
    else
    {
        return build.Concat(Make(
              projects.Except(build),
              references.Where(r => !build.Contains(r.Dependency))));
    }
}
```